# Dictionary value when deleting cell - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, dictionary

Im working in Swift/Xcode and I am new to app development, i have a tableView with 2 labels. The issue is when deleting a cell of my tableView. I need to get the data of one of the cell labels but the app crashes with the fatal error - 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

I have set up break points so that i can check if the dictionary has anything stored in it, which it does, there is an element stored in it.

Appreciate any help

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myCustomCell

       self.cost = self.total
      // This line gives me the error** self.total = self.cost - self.dict[cell.cellPrice.text!]!
       self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(self.total)"

       self.dict.removeValueForKey(cell.cellTitle!.text!)
       tableView.reloadData()
       saveState()



}
```

This my code to set up the cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
   let cell: myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCustomCell 
   var myDataSource : [String] = Array(self.dict.keys) 
   let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String 
   cell.cellTitle?.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row] 
   cell.cellPrice?.text = "£(self.dict[key]!)"
   self.saveState() 
   return cell 
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting the cell in `commitEditingStyle`? Get the value from your data model, not from the cell.

Comment: I think that @creeperspeak has the right answer. The problem is the forced unwrap "!" which is unsafe.

Comment: OP maybe want to know why is he getting this nil in his code. This answer won't make nil go away. It will stop a crash but not solve the problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to force unwrap. I guess it's cellPrice label or it text but one of those things. Figure out which one is nil.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I updated my answer. It's easier to say debug in this case beacuse there's no a lot things which could be a problem.

Comment: @creeperspeak This my code to set up the cell:  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCustomCell
        var myDataSource : [String] = Array(self.dict.keys)
        let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.cellTitle?.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellPrice?.text = "£\(self.dict[key]!)"
        self.saveState()
        return cell

    }

Comment: If you can add this code to your question so we could better help you.

Comment: I used code above which stops the app from crashing and the cell is deleted, great! but i need the 'cellPrice' value to subtract from the 'total' textLabel, as each cell has an amount and the grand total(totalLabel) is displayed underneath tableView.

Comment: Ok so you are drawing your tableView like this. Are cell's labels having values you want them to have or are they empty?

Comment: They have the value i want them to have

Comment: You said your dict have value in it so it must be a label in cell which is nil. On time when you are deleting it, it still have right values on labels?

Comment: Yes when deleting values are correct. The cell gets deleted and dictionary removed from array but 'cellPrice' not deducted from the 'total'

Comment: Beacuse it's looks like its not present when you are calculating cellPrice.

Comment: I don't know why as its present in the debugger when i set a break point and call 'po self.dict'

Comment: Dict is initialized but not the label or its text by the looks of things try doing the same but with cell label and its text.

Comment: Ok so this 'po cell.cellPrice' gives me text = '£550.0' which is the correct amount

Comment: And po 'cell.cellTitle' gives me text = 'Byron' which is also correct

Comment: ok now try self.dict[cell.cellPrice.text!] I think there is a problem.

Comment: Bingo, your right self.dict[cell.cellPrice.text!] gives me nil

Comment: So you dont have this [key:value] in a dict. There's your problem! :D

Comment: But why is that ? and how do i fix it?

Comment: You need to add this value when you are setuping your dictionary to use it here.

Comment: I thought i did that when i set up the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and created the dict in viewdidload after data had been passed from previous VC by doing the following self.dict[self.recievedSelection.choice] = self.recievedSelection.choiceValue

Comment: It looks like your dict doesn't have this key. So you should work out why is it. I can't help without seeing your code. But we are getting somewhere. If I helped somehow please consider plusing and accepting an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i really appreciate it. I have given you helpful feedback. Now i know which part is the problem i just have to keep working at it till its fixed. Somehow work out why dict doesnt store that key

Comment: Ok accept an answer and pluse would be appriciated. Ofc if you need more help feel free to ask another question!

Comment: Ok i will post another question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to see more of your code to know how you are setting properties of `myCustomCell`, but it looks like either `cellPrice.text` is nil or `self.dict[cell.cellPrice.text]` is nil.  You should just unwrap those optionals safely rather than trying to force them.  That'd look something like this:

```
if let price = cell.cellPrice.text, let priceValue = self.dict[price] {
    self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(priceValue)"
    ...
}
```

In general you should stay away from force unwrapping (using !) unless you're just writing really quickly for testing or something.  It makes debugging harder.